# Having trouble with array pointer in C

Tags: c

Hi guys I am a beginner in C, and I have trouble when testing array pointer and allocating dynamic memory.

```
int x,i=0;
char *myChar;

printf("Please enter the length: ");
scanf("%d",&x);
myChar = (char*)malloc(x*sizeof(char));
printf("Please enter %d characters:",x);
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    scanf("%c ",&myChar[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    printf("%c",myChar[i]);
}
free(myChar);
```

If I enter 5 for length, and "hello" for character array, I get "hell" instead of "hello", which is not fun. Anybody can help me with this? Thanks

Comment: To store `"hello"` *as a string* you need 6 bytes, with the last holding the terminating `'\0'`. You're storing and accessing individual characters in an array, so you don't need the `'\0'`, but it's a somewhat odd approach.

Comment: There is a danger lurking, but not met here, but if you decide to print the whole string in one go with `printf("%s", myChar);` or use one of the library string functions, it would fail for two reasons. First it has no zero-terminator, and even if you put one after the input loop with `myChar[i]=0;` it would fail because the buffer is not big enough unless you did `myChar=malloc(x+1);`. And note, your other frills in `malloc()` call are uneccessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely culprit is the following `scanf` call:

```
scanf("%c ",&myChar[i]);
```

Change it to the following:

```
scanf(" %c", &myChar[i]);
```

Note that I switched the blank space to before the `%c` conversion specifier.

Here's what's happening: when you enter your array size, the input stream will contain the following characters: `'5' '\n'`.  The first `scanf` call consumes the `'5'` and leaves the `'\n'` in the input stream.

When you enter `hello`, the input stream contains `'\n' 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\n'`.  The next `scanf` call reads `'\n'` from the input stream and assigns it to `myChar[0]` because `%c` does not skip leading whitespace.  So you wind up reading `'\n' 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l'` from the input stream and assigning them to your `myChar` array.

By putting the blank space before the `%c` conversion specifier, you tell `scanf` to skip any leading whitespace and consume the next non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your `scanf()` change it to

```
scanf(" %c",&myChar[i]);
```

The space before the `%c` will consume the newline character in the buffer because of the enter key following the value of `x` else the newline character will be fetched as by `%c` in the loop. So have a space before `%c` not after it.

Answer (score 0):

The first `scanf` isn't *eating* the return key used to finish the length entry, so it becomes the first of your `x` characters read, so the last character *isn't* being read.  @Gopi's fix will address this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call

```
fflush (stdin);
```

after the fifth line